# Debezium MS SQL Connector with Windows Service Account from Openshift(RHEL 7.9)

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, mssql-jdbc

We are using trying to create one source connector using one Windows service account (eg - serviceaccount@domain.com) and password and it is showing the error

> Login Failed for User 'serviceaccount@domain.com'

We tried with version Debezium 1.9.6. Any one else tried with service account other than sql database user and password.? Has anyone tried Kerberos? CDC is already enabled in DB.

We tried creating connector as mentioned below.

```json
 {
    "name": "inventory-connector", 
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector", 
        "database.hostname": "192.168.99.100", 
        "database.port": "1433", 
        "database.user": "serviceaccount@domain.com", 
        "database.password": "Password!", 
        "database.dbname": "testDB", 
        "database.server.name": "fullfillment", 
        "table.include.list": "dbo.customers", 
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", 
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.fullfillment" 
    }
}
```

Comment: `database.user` and `database.password` are for specifying SQL Logon authentication credentials, i.e.: username and password for an account that's created within the SQL Server instance itself. You don't use those properties for Windows/Active Directory/Kerberos accounts. Ref: [Connector Properties](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-connector-properties)

Comment: Figured it. Additionally added "database.domain":"domain.com", database.authenticationScheme": "NTLM" and "database.integratedSecurity": "true"